# AngularJS - Passing elements into script and Selectors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When in the template i provide

```
<div id="container">
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <button value="send" ng-click="testMethod($parent)">
</div>
```

in the JS:

```
$scope.testMethod = function(element) {
    console.log("sending message");
    console.log(element); // comes back with an element
    console.log(element.children()); // <-- this throws an exception
    console.log(element.firstChild()); // <-- this throws an exception
}
```

Simply, how can I select a child element of a parent by passing the element into the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Controller` methods as the one you have created above should not be manipulating html elements directly. They should only work on objects to which the templates are bound to.

If you want to  interact with UI elements in code, you create a `directive` in AngularJS and the element and its children should be easily accessible in the directive functions. Using attributes you can bind directive scope to controller scope properties and methods and create a wiring between business logic in controller functions and UI elements in directive functions.

There is plenty of documentation on AngularJS on `Directives` and `Scopes`, without going through it will be very difficult to achieve the simplest of tasks in AngularJS.

Comment: Thank yo for the explanation, would it be possible to get an example? I've been slamming my face into my monitor all day over this (me and Angular only just met). Specifically im just trying to create a simple "submit-like" thing, trying to acquire the contents of the textarea (there are many like it in a list (think: messenger), none of the elements created WITH angular)

Comment: There is a Zippy example (basic) on this page http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: The thing about Angular is it takes a while to get a grip around the patterns and terminology. Once you do that, everything makes sense and is much easier. I would read guides on their site once from top to bottom even if you don't digest everything in one go. Specially `directives`, `services`, `scope`, `filters`.

Answer (score 0):

Ketan's answer is right,  and I would add why do you want to get the child elements?  You generally don't manipulate html directly from a controller however you should and would update your $scope's data which can drive changes on your page.  Just taking your example in a plain old controller we don't care about `element` but about the scope's data.

This simple example will update the textarea when the button is clicked, show another div. and add an item to the items array.  With jQuery we'd be manipulating the dom via javascript like `$(el).val()` and `$(el).find()` etc, but in an angular controller we don't worry about the dom, only the data:

Demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/aL6p09DrQsUotu7vnceZ

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.message = "Some data";
    $scope.testMethod = function() {
    $scope.items.stuff.push($scope.message);
    $scope.clicked = true;    
    $scope.message = $scope.message  + ' you clicked me.';
  }
  $scope.items = {stuff:['one', 'two', 'three'],id:1,name:'yeah'}


});

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="container" ng-form>

    <textarea name="message" ng-model="message"></textarea>
    <button value="send" ng-click="testMethod()">Send</button>
</div>
  <div ng-show="clicked">
    I was clicked
  </div>


  <h2>{{items.name}}</h2>
  <div ng-repeat='item in items.stuff'>
    {{item}}
  </div>

</body>
```

The above was controller centric and manipulating elements on the page is part of angular with directives and without a little more information on exactly what you are trying to achieve (is it getting form input values?) it is hard to point you in the exact direction for this particular problem.